# Почему-то не работает log4net на другой машине

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

В общем, на моей машине(Win 7) логи нормально пишутся, запускаю программу на другой(Win Server 2003) машине, а там пишется вот такая шляпа:

> 2017-11-23 10:00:11,761 [1] DEBUG Test.Program [2017-11-23
>   10:00:13,527 [1] DEBUG Test.Program [2017-11-23 10:00:13,761 [1] ERROR
>   Test.Program [2017-11-23 10:00:14,449 [1] DEBUG Test.Program
>   [2017-11-23 10:00:15,918 [1] ERROR Test.Program [

На моей машине, все четко пишется:

> 2017-11-23 09:43:29,161 [1] DEBUG Test.Program [(null)] - Запуск
>   программы 2017-11-23 09:43:34,167 [1] DEBUG Test.Program [(null)] -
>   Проблема 2017-11-23 09:43:34,677 [1] ERROR Test.Program [(null)] -
>   System.IO.IOException: Не найдено сетевое имя.

Т.е видны сообщения.

Конфигурация вот такая:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <target value="Console.Error" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\LogFile.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="15000KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Версия либы последняя и взята из Nuget

Comment: В логе тоже переносов строк нет? или это сюда так вставилось?

Comment: @4per, да. Тупо все одной строкой. Не понимаю, в чем косяк. Тестировал на Windows 7, запускаю на Win Server 2003 и такая ерунда...

Comment: @iluxa1810 попробуйте другим редактором открывать логи. Такая ерунда случается из-за окончаний строк в стиле linux (т.е. LF) когда редактор только CR+LF умеет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну блокнот и Notepad++ открывают в таком виде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм... лучшее враг хорошего. Откатился на древнюю версию log4net 2013 года с 2017 и все заработало.

Получается, что свежий log4net не совместим со старой виндой. Можно еще поэксперементировать с версиями и найти максимальную рабочую версию. 2013 просто была проверенная.

Не знаю... может быть в новом log4net нужно дополнительно сконфигурировать для нормальной работы, но инфу я не нашел.

Answer (score -1):

**1. Перед тем как использовать логгер, попробуйте переконфигурировать log4net.**

`log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

В некоторых случаях это помогает.

**2. Попробуйте создать отдельный логгер в конфигурации:**

```
<logger name="Name" >
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="AppenderName1" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Все это я делаю. Если бы не было первого, то лог бы вообще не писался. Второе есть в примере конфигурации.